# How to optimise my Minecraft clone in Ursina Python Properly

Tags: python, optimization, ursina

When I run the code, the area around the player which is within 5m from them intially is able to place blocks, which is handled under **Placing Blocks** however, when I move and attempt to place blocks outside the 5m radius the blocks dont place even tho I just copied and pasted the code under **"REMOVING COLLIDERS ON ANY ENTITIES THAT ARE NOT NEAR"** and put it in a function which is run whenever the player moves, which should work.

```
import math

from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
from perlin_noise import PerlinNoise
import random
from distance_calc import distance_calc

noise = PerlinNoise(octaves=5, seed=random.randint(-1000000000000, 10000000000))
optimal_distance = 5
#set up app
app = Ursina()

# VARAIBLES
selected_block = "grass"
water = load_texture("assets/water.jpg"),

# TEXTURES
block_textures = {
    'grass': load_texture("assets/grass.jpg"),
    'dirt': load_texture("assets/dirt.jpg"),
    'stone': load_texture("assets/stone.jpg"),
    'bedrock': load_texture("assets/bedrock.jpg"),
    'faux_bedrock': load_texture("assets/bedrock.jpg"),
    'cobblestone': load_texture("assets/cobblestone.jpg")
}


# CREATE PLAYER
player = FirstPersonController(
    mouse_sensitivity=Vec2(100, 100),
    scale=0.85,
    position=(0, 25, 0)
)

class Block(Entity):

    def input(self, key):
        if key == "w" or key == "a" or key == "s" or key == "d":
            
            # UPDATING THE COLLIDERS WHEN PLAYER MOVES
            self.distance_from_player = distance_calc(player.x, player.y, player.z, self.x, self.y, self.z)
            if self.distance_from_player < optimal_distance:
                self.collider = "box"
            else:
                self.collider = None
            # UPDATING THE VIEWING WHEN PLAYER MOVES
            if self.distance_from_player < 10:
                self.visible = True
            else:
                self.visible = False


    def __init__(self, position, block_type):
        super().__init__(
        position=position,
        model="cube",
        scale=1,
        origin_y=-0.5,
        texture=block_textures.get(block_type),

    )
        self.block_type = block_type
        
        # OTIMIZATION
        
        # REMOVING COLLIDERS ON ANY ENTITIES THAT ARE NOT NEAR
        self.distance_from_player = distance_calc(player.x, player.y, player.z, self.x, self.y, self.z)
        if self.distance_from_player < optimal_distance:
            self.collider ="box"
        else:
            self.collider = None
        
        # SETTING VIEWING DISTANCE TO 10 SO ANY ENTITIES FURTHER ARE NOT SHOWN
        if self.distance_from_player < 10:
            self.visible = True
        else:
            self.visible = False



mini_block = Entity(
    parent=camera,
    model="cube",
    scale=0.2,
    origin_y=-0.5,
    texture=block_textures.get(selected_block),
    collider="box",
    position = (0.3, -0.25, 0.45),
)


# GROUND
ground = Entity(
    model = 'plane',
    scale = (100, 1, 100),
    texture = "water",
    texture_scale = (100, 100),
    collider = "box",
    block_type = "water",
    position=(0,-5, 0),
)

#PLACING BLOCK
def input(key):
    global selected_block
    #place block
    if key == "right mouse down":
        hit_info = raycast(camera.world_position, camera.forward, distance=10)
        if hit_info.hit:
            block = Block(hit_info.entity.position + hit_info.normal, selected_block)
    #place block
    if key == "left mouse down" and mouse.hovered_entity:
        if not mouse.hovered_entity.block_type == "bedrock":
            if not mouse.hovered_entity.block_type == "water":
                destroy(mouse.hovered_entity)


    #BLOCK CHOOSER
    if key=="1":
        selected_block = "grass"
    if key=="2":
        selected_block = "stone"
    if key=="3":
        selected_block = "faux_bedrock"
    if key=="4":
        selected_block = "cobblestone"


# TERRAIN
min_height = -2
for x in range (-25, 25):
    for z in range(-25, 25):
        height = noise([x*0.02, z*0.02])
        height = math.floor(height * 7.5)
        for y in range(height, min_height -1, -1):
            if y == min_height:
                block = Block((x,y + min_height, z), "bedrock")
            elif y == height:
                block = Block((x,y + min_height, z), "grass")
            elif height - y > 2:
                block = Block((x,y + min_height, z), "stone")
            else:
                block = Block((x,y + min_height, z), "dirt")


def update():
    mini_block.texture = block_textures.get(selected_block)


# RUN APP
app.run()
```